# Architecture for web-application with web-services

Tags: web-services, web-applications, database-design, architecture

I think about an web-application that will use web-services as a base.

- On the top-level will web-application as a presentation layer.
- On the middle-level will be business services as a business layer.
- On the bottom-level will be data management service as a data access layer.

The main idea that we can add other services as needed with as less changes as possible.

You can see application architecture on link http://postimg.org/image/430yj644h/.

Questions:

1. Which approach will be better: SOAP or REST? Is it true that SOAP it's bad approach ([SOAP or REST for Web Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76595/soap-or-rest-for-web-services))?
2. What way is better to implement authentication and Role Based Access Control (RBAC)? We'll have several services and I think each will be needed RBAC.
3. What framework will be better to use? Need to be easy and reliable.
4. We will keep news (events) with tags and structured meta data (regions and countries, cities | government or industry types | and etc.). In the future maybe we will needed a tool for defining relations between data, for example all data related for company. What DBMS (free) you think we can use for keeping such data?

UPD: I also need to make UI from widgets, so users can configure best for them.

5. What MVC framework is good for using widgets?

Comment: You'll be better off if you split this into separate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my experience my advice goes like...

1. Use REST and JSON...it will give you more reach and speed.
2. Yes in that case create a single service to cater the need of authentication for all other apps.
3. There are may framework out there...You can use Microsoft ASP.MET MVC 4 or Apache Struts. Many other frameworks are also listed at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks 
   What is appropriate for you depends on your team ...what skills they have and their comfort zone. All major frameworks work well if we use those wisely.
4. My vote is for MySQL...for more look into [What is a good free RDBMS solution for a small web project that may grow large if successful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658639/what-is-a-good-free-rdbms-solution-for-a-small-web-project-that-may-grow-large-i)

Thanks.